# How to add files from webapp directory to jar using Maven Assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, jar

I have project of following structure.

[image: Project structure]

I want to create a jar which will have 'config' and 'static' directories. Also that jar should have compiled classes as well.

So far, I have tried following but without success.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>src</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory/>
        <includes>
            <include>src/main/webapp/config/</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you need the webapp directory to be a part of the jar, why don't you put it under the java or resources directories?

Comment: I can do it for `config` directory but our project structure is like that we have one parent project and several child projects. We create a jar of child project and put it into parent project. Then parent project extract the html and other static content from child project's jar. That is why I want to create a jar with directories from wepapps directory.

Comment: does it have to be a jar file? a zip would easier to create.

Comment: The reason we are packaging child project into jar as that jar contain classes as well as html/js files. So if I creates a zip for html/JS files and a jar for classes then it would be difficult to maintain as I need to upload both to local Nexus Maven repository.

Comment: The zip will contain the jar and the html/js resources

Comment: It will create new problem as when our parent app gets started, it searches for children jars. If found, then it extract the only static content from those jars. If I put both jar and static content into single zip and extract them in startup process then that time child jar will not in classloader of parent app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that it is possible to use assembly plugin the way you want, but you can define the webapp directory as a resource of the module like this:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>webapp/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

in this case the jar that will be created, would include the compiled code and the webapp directory. (if needed you can add more  to include other resources directories.

for more information, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Hii @Tidhar, its working. I know its out of scope but can you tell me how can I generate source jar for the same ?

Comment: I would check something like this https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html